# When use Spy and PowerMock together throws RuntimeException

Tags: junit, powermock, spy

When I use Spy annotation together with the PowerMock in my JUnit test case, it throws RuntimeException, but when I use Mock annotation together with the PowerMock, the test case is working fine.
Anybody able to advise about my issue?

This is my code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DBConnectionPool.class})
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class TestAbcController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestAbcController .class.getName());

    public TestAbcController () {
    }

    @Spy
    private SampleDao mockDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private AbcController ctr;

    private BasicDataSource ds = null;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DBConnectionPool.class);
        PowerMockito.when(DBConnectionPool.getDataSource()).thenReturn(UnitTestDbConnection.getDataSource());
        }

 @Test
    public void testMain() {
   when(mockDao.getMap()).thenReturn(new HashMap());
}
```

Below is the detail of the exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on
>   PowerMock test listener
>   org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@d86a6f failed.
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoSpyAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoSpyAnnotationEngine.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:32)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.injectSpiesAndInjectToSetters(AnnotationEnabler.java:60)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:55)
>     at
>   org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue after I upgrade my mockito-core to 2.8.9 and powermock to 1.7.4